# Jackson: How to deserialize json with shorthand property value

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I am struggling to find out how to deserialize following JSON with shorthand conventions into Java POJOs using Jackson.

```
[
  { 
    "id":1,
    "type": "simple"
  },
  { 
    "id":2,
    "type": { "kind": "simple" }
  },
  { 
    "id":3,
    "type": {
      "kind": "complex",
      "someOtherThing": "value"
    }
  }
]
```

The "type" property here can be either string or an object. If it is a string then it is considered to be a simple shorthand form of the same object with default properties. I.e.  1 and 2 in the example above are equivalent.

As I understand it is possible to write Custom Deserializer for the whole 'type' object. As far as I understand in that case I would have to deserialize whole 'type' object manually. But I would really want to manually process only the shorthand form and delegate the normal processing to annotation based mapper. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply define a constructor with a parameter which will create the object with a simple type. In your case your `Type` class will have a `String` constructor. Dont forget to include a noargs constructor as well.

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {
    String str = "[ {\"id\":1,\"type\":\"simple\" }, {\"id\":2,\"type\": {\"kind\":\"simple\" } }, {\"id\":3,\"type\": {\"kind\":\"complex\",\"someOtherThing\":\"value\" } }]";
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    MyObject[] objs = mapper.readValue(str.getBytes(), MyObject[].class);
    for(MyObject obj : objs) {
        System.out.println(obj.id + " " + obj.type.kind + " " + obj.type.someOtherThing);
    }
}

public static class MyObject {
    public String id;
    public Type type;
}

public static class Type {
    public String kind;
    public String someOtherThing;

    public Type() {
    }

    public Type(String kind) {
        this.kind = kind;
    }
}
```

prints out

```
1 simple null
2 simple null
3 complex value
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to write a custom `BeanDeserializer` subclass for `type`. However, you can leverage the rest of Jackson to handle the type object.

Your best option would be to `@JsonIgnore` the type property in your object. Then, in the custom deserializer, override `handleIgnoredProperty()`. In this method, do something like this:

```
protected void handleIgnoredProperty(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt, Object beanOrClass, String propName)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
  if ("type".equals(propName)) {
     if (jp.getCurrentToken() != JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
       MyObjectDeserializer myObjectDeserializer = (MyObjectDeserializer) ctxt.findRootValueDeserializer(ctxt                   .getTypeFactory().constructType(MyObject.class));
       MyObject myObject = (MyObject) myObjectDeserializer.deserialize(jp, ctxt);
       // cast beanOrClass to your object and call object.setType(myObject)
     }
     else {
        // get a StringDeserializer and call object.setType(string)
     }
  }
  else {
    super.handleIgnoredProperty(jp, ctxt, beanOrClass, propName);
  }
}
```

You may need to do some more processing to manually read the kind value with `jp.nextToken()` to get to `someOtherThing` but I hope this is enough to get you started.